# Angular 6 - How to assign a member to a result of a subscribtion in

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have the following code:

```
m_SystemOptions: KeyValueEntity[];
    OnInitializeFramework(): any
    {
        this.GetSystemSettings().subscribe(
            response  =>
            {
                if (response.IsSuccess)
                {
                    this.m_SystemOptions = response.Entities;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.UnexpectedMessage(response.ResponseMessage);
                }
            });

    }
```

Ideally, I would like it to be something like this:

```
this.m_SystemOptions = this.GetSystemSettings().SomeMagic()
or
this.m_SystemOptions = SomeMagic(this.GetSystemSettings());
or at the very worst:
 SomeMagic(this.GetSystemSettings(), this.m_SystemOptions);
```

this.GetSystemSettings is a function that returns the same type as this.m_SystemOptions

Since my code has this structure dozens of times, I would like to shorten it

All I am missing is SomeMagic()

EDIT:

I missed a small but important part
GetSystemSettings() does not return the same type directly but wrapped in some control structure that is shared across the application
Inside of it there is basically just a call to httpClient . get() that returns a subscribtion
I would like not to touch that part, its fine and generic
What I would want is to remove the repeating part I have posted above that handles both response success and failure, and change it to something more generic to make the code in the component more readable

```
export class BaseResponse
{
    IsSuccess: boolean;
    ResponseCode: number;
    ResponseMessage: string;
    ResponseExtendedMessage: string;
}
export abstract class BaseEntitiesResponse<TEntity extends BaseEntity> extends BaseResponse { Entities: TEntity[] }


export class KeyValueEntity extends BaseEntity
{
    Key: string;
    Value: string;
}


 //Get the settings
    private GetSystemSettings(): Observable<BaseEntitiesResponse<KeyValueEntity>>
    {
        return this.api.ExecuteGetAction("System", "SystemOptions");
    }
```

Comment: this.m_SystemOptions = await this.GetSystemSettings().toPromise();

But why don't you want to do this ? :
this.GetSystemSettings().subscribe(value => this.m_SystemOptions = value);

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal to `subscribe` upon calling the method. You should subscribe only when you need it, that's why `Observable` is called "lazy".
your `GetSystemSettings` should look something like:

```
this.GetSystemSettings().pipe(map(
    response  =>
    {
      if (response.IsSuccess)
      {
        return response.Entities;
      }
      else
      {
        return []; // Error message can be handled more gracefully :)
      }
     }));
```

and subscribe to the method

```
this.GetSystemSettings().subscribe(entities => this.m_SystemOptions = entities);
```

Comment: I've updated the question with more details to make it more clear

Comment: It may not be. But, the code design to subscribe in every call of `onInitializeFramework`, will give an opportunity for memory leak. Of course I may be wrong, I didn't see your whole solution, it could've been unsubscribed somewhere.